# Monkey tool in android for mouse event injections

Tags: android, mouse

I wanto to inject mouse event into an running application ( like clicking and moving the mouse pointer). Is it possible with monkey tool ? If yes, can you give me a roadmap about how to use monkey tool in android application development platform ?

Answer (score 0):

I am driving apps in emulators using Monkey.

I have a Python script that gets fed to the monkeyrunner tool. This is largely coming from the sample on the Android developer [website](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html).
It is possible to invoke activities and respond to them.
For instance here I invoke an activity, which in turn runs another one; at that point I enter 4 digits and 'click' the coordinates 100,400 on the screen corresponding to the 'ok' button.

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

    # Installs the Android package. Notice that this method returns a boolean, so you can test
    # to see if the installation worked.
    #    device.installPackage('myproject/bin/MyApplication.apk')

    # sets a variable with the package's internal name
    package = 'com.mypackage'

    # sets a variable with the name of an Activity in the package
    activity = 'com.mypackage.myactivity'

    # sets the name of the component to start
    runComponent = package + '/' + activity

    # Runs the component
    device.startActivity(component=runComponent)

    if device.getProperty('am.current.comp.class') == 'com.mypackage.anotheractivity':
        device.type('0000')
        # Click the 'Enter' button on screen at coordinates 100,400
        device.touch(100, 600, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
```

I hope that helps.